# string to int conversion of list in python

Tags: python, string, list, integer

I want to convert string list in int list in python3.x

```
b = ["1.22","1.45","1.85","2.35","3.73","5.44"]
c= [int(i) for i in b]
print(c)
```

But I am getting the error

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1.22'
```

What is the error in syntax or possible other solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.22 is not an integer. Use [`decimal.Decimal('1.23')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) or [`float('1.23')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float) instead.

Answer (score 2):

These are `floats` not `ints`, that's why you get the error, you could modify your code as such:

```
b = ["1.22","1.45","1.85","2.35","3.73","5.44"]
c = [float(i) for i in b]
print(c)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try first converting to floating point, then convert those floats to ints:

```
b = ["1.22","1.45","1.85","2.35","3.73","5.44"]
c = [int(float(i)) for i in b]
print(c)
```

This prints:

```
[1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5]
```